# Greek (non-english) characters on Raspbian Jessie when fstab

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-jessie

On my raspberry pi 2, through SSH, I hook up a USB key with some mp3 which have Greek titles.

I can read it through SSH and VNC.

I wanted to create a NAS based on [this guide][1] but I end up by doing everything in Webmin.

1. `mkdir /media/USB`
2. Through Webmin(1.780) under `System -> Disk and Network Filesystems` 
   I selected `Windows Filesystem (vfat)` because my USB is formatted as FAT32 and I clicked add mount.
3. In the **`Mounted as`** I selected `/media/USB`
4. At `Windows Filesystem` I clicked the `Disk` radio button and selected my USB from the dropdown menu.
5. I did not change nothing else. Hit save
6. From Webmin menu I choose `Servers` and select `Samba Windows File Sharing` (you have to install it first).
7. `Create a new file share`
8. I choose a name for my share and in the **`Directory to share`** I had /media/USB
9. Finally hit `Create`

Now when I reboot and I cd to /media/USB and I see the Greek titles are showing like question marks

> ?????????????? - ?????????????

and when I see them over the samba share they look like

> _69PWA~S

I have already installed Greek locales (actually I selected ALL LOCALES option to be sure) but again the nothing changed

Comment: Are the filenames written in greek and wich format do your files have?

Comment: are you connected directly to the Pi or are you using SSH?

Comment: I edited (I rewrote actually) the post. So check the answers there!