# Non-english character file names get changed on their own

Tags: pi-3, usb, raspberry-pi-os, corrupt

*[Same Problem Mentioned Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42644/greek-non-english-characters-on-raspbian-jessie-when-fstab)*

I am running Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

I have some files on a FAT32 formatted USB drive, which stores data for a Jellyfin library. When however I add files and folders with greek titles, the file names automatically get changed to names like `_Y5F46~1` (seen on SMB). When removing and adding the files again this occurs and the files don't keep their name. On Jellyfin they appear as questionmarks `????? ??????????? ???`. Everything with a greek character changes and files in english stay intact.

What could be the issue and what should I do to fix it?

*Edit: Removing the USB drive from fstab and mounting it manually didn't work. After a reboot the file names were changed again.*

*Edit 2: I generated the greek locales again and the files seem to not have changed after a reboot, will monitor over the next few days and edit accordingly.*

*Edit 3: Edit 2 doesn’t seem to work*

Comment: How is the USB drive formatted?  Basic FAT only supports ASCII.

Comment: It is formatted in FAT32, but that does not seem to be the problem, as the files appeared correctly until the reboot and it works fine on my desktop Arch Linux system. I generated the greek locales again and the files seem to not have changed after a reboot, but I will not mark this as closed yet and will monitor if anything changes before I do that.

Comment: (1) If Greek characters become ??? usually means the new translator (encoder/decoder) no longer recognizes the Greek characters. (2) I have been using Chinese Windows 10 for a couple of years without any problem in displaying Chinese characters. But Chinese Windows 10 a year ago seemed to have changed something in their character encoder/decoder and then Chinese characters could no longer be recognized and become ???.  A workaround workaround is when saving files with Chinese characters, I need to use a new encoder UTF-16LE or UTF16-BE which I never used before.

Comment: Please add relevant information to your question.

Comment: Linux uses UTF-8, which can encode anything, but it is not the same as UTF-16, so this could cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting the drive to ext4 solves this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).